# Need to fix custom page error

Tags: php, html

There is a problem that is troubling me in the custom error pages. When I visit the page it shows the error page without redirecting. I want to fix this error on my [website](http://www.purelamps.com/).
The code in which it is displaying error is given below:

```
[I][COLOR=#010293]<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "[URL]mysite.org/123.php[/URL]"
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=[URL]mysite.org/123.php[/URL]">[/COLOR][/I]
```

Can you describe what’s the problem is?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please explain in brief .. I have visited your website there is no error. share exact page url where you are getting error.

Comment: Why are you putting those words in brackets? `[URL]`, `[I]` and `[COLOR]` aren't PHP nor HTML standards, and these are the only tags that you put in your question...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect

by HTML then use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://myoryoursite.org/123.php'" />` in HEAD tag

by JavaScript then use `window.location.href = "http://myoryoursite.org/123.org";`

by php then use `header('Location: http://myoryoursite.org/123.php'); exit;` in PHP tag.

So you should first decide which way you want to use.